# Role of の in this sentence

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-の, spoken-language

「カッコイイのやってみたいと思ってます」
What's meaning of の here? How I understand: (I think) I wanna try to do something cool? (I'm not sure about カッコイイの) Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 4):

> 「カッコイイ**の**やってみたいと[思]{おも}ってます。」＝
>
> 「カッコイイ**の** + **を** + やってみたいと思ってます。」

「の」 is a nominalizer that turns the adjective 「カッコイイ」 into a noun-like form - "a カッコイイ one".

What the thing is should be clear to ***you*** from the context.  We have no way of knowing it here.

> "***I'm hoping to pull off a good one***."

(I just used the adjective "good" because I do not know what the object is that is being talked about.)